Nuxt 3.13.2 Optional chaining support for Firefox v60.8.0esr (64bit)
I have a project that uses Nuxt 3.13.2 and have optional chaining across multiple files. How do I go about transpiling the code so that it can work on older Firefox browsers v60.8.0. I have tried using the @babel/plugin-transform-optional-chaining and @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining-assign libraries but they dont seem to do anything for me.

.browserslistrc should be the one to handle that one. Not sure that Babel is still used by Vite nowadays. Firefox 60 is 6+ years old btw, damn quite some support you need here. You could also skip that part and write it in the good old fashioned way with some && etc.
